# Why my resolution of Thinkpad T450s is 1536px width?

Tags: display, thinkpad

I go to https://www.mydevice.io/ to check my computer (Thinkpad T450s) screen width, it shows the width of the screen is 1536px. However, I have checked my screen setting is 1920x1080. Is there anyone know the reason why?

[image: Mydevice.io screenshot with technical information]]

[image: Windows screen resolution settings dialog]]

Comment: Was your window maximized? That site is only measuring the width of the window.

Comment: @vlumi Yes, maximized the browser windows.

Comment: Which Browser? Did it have a border? That screen is showing 120 dpi so you're using a higher DPI setting?

Answer (score 2):

You have display scaling set to 125%. That means you can only fit 80% as much content on the screen. 80% of 1920 is 1536.

This website does not measure physical pixels. It measures logical pixels. You can easily check by zooming in your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

The reported width is not the actual physical amount of pixels, but the logical width calculated by the "device pixel ratio".
You can see the value `JS pixel ratio 1.2500` and 1920 / 1.25 = 1536.

In your browser's javascript console you can log the value with `console.log(window.devicePixelRatio);`, it's a property of the window object.

(same result on an Thinkpad X250 here)